# Vue.js doesn't update value if I use an object in another object for select option

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of posts and each post has a user. I also have a select field where I can change the post's user. However only the user's id updates on the page and not the username itself. How could I have both of them update and reflect the change?

```
data() {
    return {
        posts: [
            {
                id: 1,
                post_body: 'hello world',

                user: {
                    id: 45,
                    username: 'Johnny13'
                }
            },              
            {
                id: 2,
                post_body: 'what is up?',

                user: {
                    id: 97,
                    username: 'Billly75'
                }
            }
        ],

        users: [
            {id: 45, username: 'Johnny13'},
            {id: 97, username: 'Billly75'}
        ]
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div v-for="(post, index) in posts">
    The user for this post is:
    {{ post.user.id }} <!-- this changes -->
    {{ post.user.username }} <!-- this does not -->

    Change the post's user:
    <select v-model="post.user.id">
        <option v-for="user in users" :value="user.id">{{ user.username }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `user` object as v-model, and the same for options values. Like this:

```
<select v-model="post.user">
    <option v-for="user in users" :value="user">{{ user.username }}</option>
</select>
```